# Dynamic file intro SQL Query

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql, cron

I have this query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/logfile20200111.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE foo_db.log FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5) SET name=TRIM(@val1), type=TRIM(@val2), price=TRIM(@val3), active=TRIM(@val4), broken=TRIM(@val5);
```

I want to use a daily cronjob which will run this query and import from a file to DB my info that I need.

How can I take the file in a dynamic way?

`/logfile20200111.txt` -> this is the current file name but tomorrow will be other file `logfile20200112.txt` and so on.
the name convention for the file is `logfile[year][month][day].txt`
I need to make this query to know which filed to take each day from that location.

Example of my folder with files
[image: Example of my folder with files]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Post your attempt and explain the issue you're having with your attempt.

Comment: ...and which language are you using/asking about? PHP or Python? Choose the one you've used to make your attempts.

Answer (score -1):

please replace

```
/logfile20200111.txt
```

with

```
CONCAT('/logfile',YEAR(CURDATE()), LPAD(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()), 2, 0),LPAD(DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), 2, 0),'.txt')
```

Comment: I did tried and it says the following:  SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near CONCAT('/logfile',YEAR(CURDATE()), LPAD(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()), 2, 0),LPAD(DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), 2, 0),'.txt')